# when to use !Convert.IsDBNull?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

//What is the function of  **!Convert.IsDBNull** below. What if the table has null values and can i get the same output without using above condition to fetch the data...what could be the consequences if not used//

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {

                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))                
                {
                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                }

            }

            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands with the code you've posted, there won't be lines written when the column is null.  If you remove the `if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))` block -- i.e. leaving just `sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());` without the surrounding `if` block, then lines will always be written but will contain empty string when the column is null.

Comment: Did you mean that if I do not use "if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))" then, if in case one of the column values for a particular row is null, then the whole row will be omitted?!!!